# Custom Connector does not work "Received error from connectors..."

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I am developing a custom(very simple) connector to microsoft teams. And I am getting an ng error when I click save and a "error on connector" but it is not saved.

```
var webhookUrl = '';
var posting = '';
var name = '';
var entity = '';
var url = '';
var context;

microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function(settings) {
    webhookUrl = settings.webhookUrl;
    $("#LINK").html(webhookUrl);
});
microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function(saveEvent) {
          debugger;
microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
              url = 'http://static-resource-f-o-server.herokuapp.com/index.html';
              entity = "Test-" + context.teamId + "-context.channelId";

          });
microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
              entityId : entity,
              contentUrl: url,
              configName : 'test1'
          });
microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function(settings) {

            webhookUrl = settings.webhookUrl;
            debugger;


          });
          saveEvent.notifySuccess();
          console.info(webhookUrl);
});


console.info(webhookUrl);
```

this is my manifest.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.3/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.3",
  "id": "661fda1e-4871-4200-abaa-a24cf8987207",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "com.test1",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "http://oktana.io",
    "privacyUrl": "http://oktana.io",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "http://oktana.io"
  },
  "description": {
    "full": "this is a super awesome test",
    "short": "this is an awesome test"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon.svg",
    "color": "icon1.svg"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "661fda1e-4871-4200-abaa-a24cf8987207",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "https://static-resource-f-o-server.herokuapp.com/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "full": "test1",
    "short": "test1"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "validDomains": [
    "static-resource-f-o-server.herokuapp.com"
  ]
}
```

Im having te following error

> 2019-07-03T22:33:28.612Z ngClickDecorator: value not found in enum
>   type. value:  (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:112 e.logMessage @
>   msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1 e.error @
>   msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1 E.tryGetEnum @ shared.min.js:1
>   E.tryGetEnumAttr @ shared.min.js:1 p @ clickDecorators.min.js:1
>   (anonymous) @ clickDecorators.min.js:1 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:1
>   y.handle @ jquery.min.js:1
>
> and
>
> 2019-07-03T22:33:28.659Z Received error from connectors
>
> (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:112 e.logMessage @
>   msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1 e.error @
>   msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1 (anonymous) @
>   lazy-ng1-mod-extensibility-dialogs.js:6110 (anonymous) @
>   angular.min.js:154 e @ angular.min.js:40 (anonymous) @
>   angular.min.js:43 setTimeout (async) Zf.k.defer @ angular.min.js:43 f
>   @ angular.min.js:154 e.processMessage @
>   lazy-ng1-mod-extensibility-dialogs.js:6071 e @
>   lazy-ng1-mod-extensibility-dialogs.js:6019

And i dont see how to proceed. Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

You should call microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings() so that connector webhook registration is completed.

```
    microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
             entityId: "entityId",
             contentUrl: "Your Config URL",
             configName: "configName"
            });
```

Please take a look at sample [Connector setup](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml#L36) page.

Comment: Problematic code has this invocation